# Check if # exist in URL then remove it

Tags: javascript

When the URL has `#id-name-here` I want to apply a CSS class to the parent of that target on the page.

So given this URL...

`domain.com/#Domain`

Then the page will jump to this location in the page

`<a name="Domain"></a>`

I want to find the PARENT of `<a name="Domain"></a>`

So using javaScript I want to find the Parent of this Node like this...

`$('a[name="Domain"]').parent('.module-box').addClass('active-cat');`

which will add the class `active-cat` to the Parent of my target Node.

So I need help making this more Dynamic, so `Domain` could be any value...

I am able to get the `Domain` portion from the URL with `location.hash`.
Then do this....

```
var activeCat = location.hash;
$('a[name="' + activeCat + '"]').parent('.module-box').addClass('active-cat');
```

This almost works except my `activeCat` contains the `#` and I need to remove that.

So if someone can help me....

1. Remove `#` from `var activeCat = location.hash;`
2. Check to make sure `var activeCat = location.hash;` even exist before running the other code?

My end result...

[image: http://codedevelopr.com/screenshots/2013-04-30_08-52-47.png]

Comment: Why use `<a name>` anyway? Just give the element you want to target an `id`, and link to that with `href="#id"`.

Comment: @CBroe hey for whatever reason I guess I didnt even think that would work as I have always seen it done as an empty <a> on the page, Another reason in my live project there is an existing ID for the parent that is an ID number which I am not able to get ahead of time where the actual link to the page is built.  Possibly I can use `name` on the parent or have more then 1 `id`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove that `#`:

```
 var activeCat = location.hash.replace('#', '');
```

Comment: Great, I wasn;t sure if I needed to use regex or not.   In JavaScript, do I need to double check to make sure this is set or not before trying to work with it?

Comment: @jasondavis It's safe to call `replace` on `location.hash`.